# BigQuery to Snowflake using external tables

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've created a [pipeline](https://github.com/budaesandrei/analytics-pipelines-snowflake/) to export data from BigQuery into Snowflake using Google Cloud services. I'm seeing some issues as the original data source is Firebase. The way Firebase exports analytics data is in a dataset called `analytics_{GA_project_id}` and the events are sent to a partitioned table called `events_{YYYYMMDD}`. The pipeline runs smoothly but after a few days I've noticed when running the gap analysis, there is more data in BigQuery (approx 3% at times) than in Snowflake. I've raised a ticket with Firebase and Google Analytics for Firebase and they confirmed there are events that are delayed up to 3 days. I was looking at what other solutions I'd potentially explore and Snowflake can also connect to an External Table hosted in Google Cloud (GCS).

Is there a way to create a replicated table that automatically syncs with BigQuery to push the data in an external table Snowflake can connect with?

The process I've set up relies on a scheduled query to unload any new daily table in GCS which is cost-efficient...I could change the query to have an additional check for new data but every time I'd have to scan the entire 2 months worth of data (or assume only 3 days delay which is not good practice) so this will add a lot more consumption.

I hope there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: Have you given any thoughts to using [Snowpipe](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-intro.html) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find a solution by inserting an additional column using a Scheduled Script called `gcs_export_timestamp`. On every run it checks if there is a new daily table and exports it and then loops through the already exported tables where `gcs_export_timestamp` is null (meaning new rows). I've described the process [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72446698/how-to-capture-delta-rows-in-bigquery-export).

Answer (score 1):

I think you found a limitation of BigQuery's `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`: It won't tell you when a table was updated last.

For example

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `bigquery-public-data`.stackoverflow.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

shows that all these tables where created in 2016 — but there's no way to see that they were updated 3 months ago.

I'm looking at the "Create the BigQuery Scheduled Script" you shared at https://github.com/budaesandrei/analytics-pipelines-snowflake/blob/main/firebase-bigquery-gcs-snowflake/Analytics%20Pipeline%20DevOps%20-%20Firebase%20to%20Snowflake.ipynb.

My recommendation is instead of relying on a BigQuery scheduled function, to start doing this outside BigQuery to have access to the whole API. Exports will be cheaper this way too.

For example, the command line `bq show bigquery-public-data:stackoverflow.posts_answers` will show you the `Last modified` date for that table.

Let's skip the command line, and let's look at the API directly.

- `tables.list` can help you find all tables created after certain date: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/list
- then iterating with `table.get` will get you the `last modified` for each: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#Table
- then a `job.insert` can extract that table to GCS for Snowpipe to automatically import: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#JobConfigurationExtract
- make sure to give the exports of the same table a new name, so Snowpipe can identify as new tables
- then you can use `METADATA$FILENAME` to deduplicate the imports of updated versions of the same table in Snowflake: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-metadata.html

All of these are available in the Python BigQuery SDK. You'll just need to rely on a different scheduler and runtime, but the best news is you'll save a lot in  BigQuery exports, as they are mostly free when you use this way instead of inside BigQuery.

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#data_extraction_pricing

Comment: hm.. I think you are suggesting to export the same tables again in GCS and then run a separate deduplication task in Snowflake. The raw table in snowflake feeds into several other tasks that are not in my control. I think that would cause issues with aggregations we have down the line unless I implement the deduplication task first then trigger the aggregation tasks to be triggered after this task...

Comment: Yup, in Snowflake you could apart the new rows by comparing both tables (previous and new) using the filename metadata

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is just the nature of the GA load to Bigquery process. Google say that same day data is loaded at least 3 times a day (no further detail given) and if there is an error, it is rolled back.

Looking at our own data, there is usually 2 intraday tables on any given day so the last fully loaded date is 2 days ago. If the final intraday load (which changes it from intraday to final table) has an error then there is a possibility that the last full day is from 3 days ago

I'm not familiar with firebase myself but one way to avoid this in BQ directly is to only query the final tables (those in the format ga_sessions_YYYYMMDD)

Comment: Yes, I am only querying events_YYYYMMDD tables...but even so, there are more events being inserted the next day up to 3 days after. If you try to record the count(*) of a recent table...let's say events_20220123 and do the same count tomorrow you will see a higher amount of events