# How to capture delta rows in BigQuery Export

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

I have some queries that run hourly and export the data from BigQuery to GCS. The daily tables seem to be updated over the next 2 days. Has anyone found a way to get the delta rows between what was exported to GCS and what was inserted in BigQuery?

This is what I am currently running (which ignores the missing data) as a scheduled script

```sql
DECLARE tables ARRAY <STRING>;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `project.analytics_xxx.daily_export_log`
(
    table_name STRING,
    insert_date TIMESTAMP
);

SET tables = (SELECT
    ARRAY_AGG(TABLE_NAME) TABLES
FROM
    `project.analytics_xxx.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`
WHERE
    REGEXP_CONTAINS(TABLE_NAME, 'events_\\d{8}') AND
    TABLE_NAME NOT IN (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM `project.analytics_xxx.daily_export_log`)
);


FOR tab IN 
    (SELECT * FROM UNNEST(tables))
DO
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '''
    EXPORT DATA
    OPTIONS ( uri = CONCAT('gs://bucket/live/', format_timestamp('%Y/%m/%d/', current_timestamp()), ''' || "'" || tab.f0_ || "'" || ''', '/*_', format_timestamp('%Y%m%d%H%M%S', current_timestamp()), '.json.gz'),
        format='JSON',
        compression='GZIP',
        overwrite=FALSE ) AS
    SELECT * FROM `project.analytics_xxx.''' || tab.f0_ || '''` ''';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '''
    INSERT INTO `project.analytics_xxx.daily_export_log` SELECT ''' || "'" || tab.f0_ || "'" || ''' table_name, current_timestamp() insert_date
    ''';
END FOR
```

I tried using `event_timestamp + event_server_timestamp_offset` as a cutoff measure but that failed as `event_timestamp` is device synced so if users have altered their system time then their timestamps would be way off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to fix the issue by appending a `gcs_export_timestamp` column to every export table.

```sql
DECLARE tables ARRAY <STRING>;

/************************************************************************************************************
*                                             DAILY EVENTS EXPORT                                           *
************************************************************************************************************/

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `project.analytics_xxx.daily_export_log`
(
    table_name STRING,
    insert_date TIMESTAMP
)
OPTIONS
(
  expiration_timestamp=TIMESTAMP "3000-01-01"
);

SET tables = (SELECT
    ARRAY_AGG(TABLE_NAME) TABLES
FROM
    `project.analytics_xxx.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`
WHERE
    REGEXP_CONTAINS(TABLE_NAME, 'events_\\d{8}') AND
    TABLE_NAME NOT IN (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM `project.analytics_xxx.daily_export_log`)
);


FOR tab IN 
    (SELECT * FROM UNNEST(tables))
DO
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '''
    EXPORT DATA
    OPTIONS ( 
        uri = CONCAT('gs://bucket/live/', format_timestamp('%Y/%m/%d/', current_timestamp()), ''' || "'" || tab.f0_ || "'" || ''', '/*_', format_timestamp('%Y%m%d%H%M%S', current_timestamp()), '.json.gz'),
        format='JSON',
        compression='GZIP',
        overwrite=FALSE 
        ) AS
    SELECT * FROM `project.analytics_xxx.''' || tab.f0_ || '''` 
    ''';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '''
    INSERT INTO `project.analytics_xxx.daily_export_log` SELECT ''' || "'" || tab.f0_ || "'" || ''' table_name, current_timestamp() insert_date
    ''';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '''
    ALTER TABLE `project.analytics_xxx.''' || tab.f0_ || '''`
    ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS gcs_export_timestamp TIMESTAMP
    ''';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '''
    UPDATE `project.analytics_xxx.''' || tab.f0_ || '''` SET
    gcs_export_timestamp = current_timestamp()
    WHERE gcs_export_timestamp IS NULL
    ''';
END FOR;


/************************************************************************************************************
*                                             DELAYED EVENTS EXPORT                                         *
************************************************************************************************************/

SET tables = (SELECT
    ARRAY_AGG(TABLE_NAME) TABLES
FROM
    `project.analytics_xxx.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`
WHERE
    REGEXP_CONTAINS(TABLE_NAME, 'events_\\d{8}')
);

FOR tab IN 
    (SELECT * FROM UNNEST(tables))
DO
/************  CHECK IF DAILY TABLE WAS OVERWRITTEN AND RE-ADD THE gcs_export_timestamp COLUMN  ************/
    BEGIN
        IF (SELECT 1 FROM `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = tab.f0_ AND column_name = 'gcs_export_timestamp') IS NULL THEN
            IF (SELECT 1 FROM `project.analytics_xxx.daily_export_log` WHERE table_name = tab.f0_) IS NOT NULL THEN
                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '''
                ALTER TABLE `project.analytics_xxx.''' || tab.f0_ || '''`
                ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS gcs_export_timestamp TIMESTAMP
                ''';

                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '''
                UPDATE `project.analytics_xxx.''' || tab.f0_ || '''` SET
                gcs_export_timestamp = (SELECT insert_date FROM `project.analytics_xxx.daily_export_log` WHERE table_name = \'''' || tab.f0_ || '''\')
                WHERE gcs_export_timestamp IS NULL
                ''';
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END;
/*****************************  EXPORT DATA WHERE gcs_export_timestamp IS NULL  ****************************/
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '''
        CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE _SESSION.tmp AS
        SELECT * FROM `project.analytics_xxx.''' || tab.f0_ || '''` WHERE gcs_export_timestamp IS NULL
        ''';

        IF (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM _SESSION.tmp) > 0 THEN
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '''
            EXPORT DATA
            OPTIONS ( 
                uri = CONCAT('gs://bucket/delayed/', format_timestamp('%Y/%m/%d/', current_timestamp()), ''' || "'" || tab.f0_ || "'" || ''', '/*_', format_timestamp('%Y%m%d%H%M%S', current_timestamp()), '.json.gz'),
                format='JSON',
                compression='GZIP',
                overwrite=FALSE 
                ) AS
            SELECT * FROM _SESSION.tmp 
            ''';

            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '''
            UPDATE `project.analytics_xxx.''' || tab.f0_ || '''` SET
            gcs_export_timestamp = current_timestamp()
            WHERE gcs_export_timestamp IS NULL
            ''';
        END IF;
    EXCEPTION WHEN ERROR THEN END;
END FOR;
```